# http.get and query string in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

In Node.js (using Express.js), when I call `http.request` like such:

```
var options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 80,
    path: '/',
    query: {name: "John Doe", age: 50} // <---- problem here
};
http.request(options, function(response) { ... });
```

all is well, except the `query` part of options is ignored. Documentation says the query string must be constructed manually, and passed inside `path`: something like `path: '/?name=John%20Doe&age=50'`.

What is the best way to achieve that? `query` is a simple hash of string->{string, number}.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're looking for is the **querystring** library http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

And also, you might be interested in this HTTP client request library https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
var qs = require('querystring');
qs.stringify({ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' })
// returns
'foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge='
```

Comment: what about JSON.stringify ?